# to view the text inputed by user in form action tag

Tags: html

Log in name of my users are not showing by my tags
How can i view the text or file that inputed by users on my HTML website in 'form action'-`<input type=text>` or `<input type=file>`?
I have already tried by simple tags

Eg:your logged in to my website by name:'USER'
And in 2nd page i want to view your name 
As "hi USER"

Comment: It's not massively clear what you're asking or what technologies you're using, please post the code you've got and someone may be able to help you!

Comment: 1. Pick a programming language. 2. Read up on how to interface it with your webserver. 3. Write some software. 4. Submit the form to it.

Comment: Use session http://www.formget.com/login-form-in-php/ as shown in this tutorial.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question isn't all that clear. Within each input field you want to save. Try putting the users value in there:

```
input(type="text", name="email", value=user.email, placeholder="email")
```

The above is in jade template format so might look different from yours. If you added some code and a little more information to your question, you'd get the answers your looking for.

Best of luck.